# GCC linux 5.1 does not warn when comparing signed and unsigned ints

Tags: c, linux, gcc

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        int a[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); ++i) {
            printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I using GCC 5.1.1 (Redhat).
I remember when I used this code in GCC lower I get a warning about signed and unsigned. So why I have no warning when using it in GCC 5.1.1?
I hope somebody can help me explain this question. Thanks so much!

Comment: did you try adding `-Wall` and `-Wextra` options?

Comment: First, you should use `size_t` as iteration variable, but you probably knew that already. But then, why should the compiler warn here? It is easy to prove that your `i` variable is always positive, unless you have overflow. Here the compiler knows the upper bound (`10`) at compile time, so it will never overflow.

Comment: Thanks @SouravGhosh. That's it. When I using -Wextra option I get a warning. So why older GCC I don't use -Wextra it also get a warning?

Comment: `i` can be statically proven to not become negative nor overflow ... I would consider a warning here unnecessary noise.

Comment: Which version of gcc produces that warning without `-Wextra` ?

Comment: @JensGustedt I know it, but I just want sure it will warning me in other some case.

Comment: As is iterated often on stackoverflow, always enable all the warnings when compiling.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
 -Wextra
```

to your compiling flags.

Comment: is -Wextra the same as -Wall?

Comment: No, they are different and affect different kind of errors.  Your specific error is catched by  `-Wextra `. However, I always suggest to use both  `-Wextra ` and  `-Wall`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct warning option to enable is `-Wsign-compare` which is not included by default and also not included in `-Wall`. `-Wsign-compare` is also enabled by `-Wextra`, so either use `-Wsign-compare` or `-Wextra`. For information, C does not require any diagnostic for comparison between signed and unsigned operands.

> I remember when I used this code in GCC lower I get a warning about signed and unsigned.

I tried on `gcc` 4.8.1 and `-Wsign-compare` is also not included in `-Wall`.

From `gcc` [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> -Wsign-compare
>
> Warn when a comparison between signed and unsigned values could produce an incorrect result when the signed value is converted to unsigned. This warning is also enabled by -Wextra; to get the other warnings of -Wextra without this warning, use -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare.